# WCF WebGet parameter pass, you can pass the output parameter (out)?

Tags: wcf

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetAwardList?COUNT={COUNT}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    List<discount_awardModel> GetAwardList(out int COUNT);
```

Through the browser call "http://localhost:50590/WCFService/Product/PublicProductService.svc/GetAwardList? COUNT=1"

The error:

> “/”Server error in application.
>   The operation "GetAwardList" in the Convention "IPublicProductService" should have a UriTemplate, which has the name "COUNT", but the operation does not have an input parameter for this name.
>
> Description: an exception that occurs during the execution of the current Web request. Please check the stack trace information to understand the details of the source of the error and the code that causes the error.
>
> Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: agreed with the name "count" parameters UriTemplate IPublicProductService operating GetAwardList ", but the operation and not the name of the input parameters.
>
> Source error:
>
> An exception is generated during the execution of the current Web request. You can use the following exception stack trace information to determine the cause and location of the exception.
>
> Stack trace:
>
> InvalidOperationException: agreed with the name "count" parameters UriTemplate IPublicProductService operating GetAwardList ", but the operation and not the name of the input parameters.

Comment: No. What do you expect this to do? A WebGet is invoked through an HTTP request, which cannot be modified once received.

Comment: I expect to use WebGet to send variable of method,the variable is decorated by the keyword of 'out'.

Comment: Whatever you want to return from a WebGet, you'll have to return from the method itself. If you want to return a `List<T>` and an `int`, you'll have to create a DTO containing properties to hold both.